# linux shell sed command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I have file `sedFile.txt` which has string in format `CONNECTION='mysql://user:user@10.79.19.2:3308/SSMS/SUBSCRIBE';`

I created one script which has following lines:

```
fin=CONNECTION='mysql://user:user@10.79.19.2:3308/SSMS/SUBSCRIBE';  
repla=connection  
sed  -i "s/\$fin/$repla/g" /home/sedFile.txt
```

Even though the script is running, it's not doing changes in my file.

I tried following:

```
sed  -i 's/${fin}/${repla}/g' /home/sedFile.txt  
sed  -i 's/^$fin/$repla/g' /home/sedFile.txt  
sed  -i "s/$fin/$repla/g" /home/sedFile.txt  
sed  -i "s/${fin}/${repla}/g" /home/sedFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the single quotes to be included in the pattern you have to quote or escape them:

```
fin="CONNECTION='mysql://user:user@10.79.19.2:3308/SSMS/SUBSCRIBE'"
```

then, use any of the four lines you tried (i.e. not the one with `\$fin`).

**Update:** In order to make `sed` work, you cannot use `/` to separate the pattern and the substitution, because this character exists in the string already. Use a different separator:

```
sed -i "s,$fin,$repla,g" /home/sedFile.txt
```

Comment: i tried like u said ..The script is working too...But it is not replacing the string ...:(

Answer (score 1):

Might be the same as the other answers, but I doesn't hurt to try

```
fin="CONNECTION='mysql://user:user@10.79.19.2:3308/SSMS/SUBSCRIBE';"
repla="connection"
sed -i "s|${fin}|${repla}|g" /home/sedFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fin="CONNECTION='mysql://user:user@10.79.19.2:3308/SSMS/SUBSCRIBE'"
repla=connection
  in=$fin out=$repla perl -pi.nk -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g'  /home/sedFile.txt
```